# Taurus - Overriding a jmeter property in test endpoint

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0, taurus

How to override a test endpoint in .jmx file from Taurus yaml. My jmx file includes both GET and POST methods.
Currently i have set the url like ‘${__P(url)}/api/login’
in  jmx and in Taurus as of below:

> execution:
>   - scenario: jmeter
>   scenarios:
>    jmeter:
>      script: sample-test.jmx
>   requests:
>    - url: 'endpoint'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the problem and the solution is as of below

Taurus command line: bzt -o settings.env.TESTING_URL=$TESTING_URL test.yaml
Note: The setting .env will read the dynamic value and store it on TESTING_URL

Within the yaml file add the below lines:
modules:
  jmeter:
    properties:
      TESTING_URL: ${TESTING_URL}

in Jmeter-> ${__P(TESTING_URL)}

Answer (score 0):

`__P` search for JMeter property, which according to [Taurus scenario based properties](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/)

> Scenario-level properties are set like this:
>
> ```
> scenarios:
>     prop_example: 
>       properties:
>          my-hostname: www.prod.com
> ```

Comment: i am getting the error 'on HTTP response code: java.net.NoRouteToHostException,Non HTTP response message: No route to host (Host unreachable'

Comment: I was able to fix the above issue . Could you please guide me how to set a run time environment variable in Taurus.yaml file.   In my case i am getting the URL during run time. modules:
  jmeter:
   properties:
    TESTING_URL: ${TESTING_URL}. During the test i dont see the actual value getting substituted

Comment: Use __setProperty JMeter function to override property

Comment: i am using ${__P(TESTING_URL)} in the jmeter and in Taurus modules:
  jmeter:
   properties:
  system-properties:
    TESTING_URL: ${TESTING_URL}

Comment: The error i see as 'Non HTTP response message: Illegal character in authority at index 7: http://${TESTING_URL}/api'. Looks like Taurus is not able to get the environment variable correctly